# How to disable the audio and subtitles settings in AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, avplayerviewcontroller

I would like to remove the audio and the subtitle settings button from the player (iOS8, iOS9):

[image: controls of the AVPlayerViewController player]

Player's controller initialization:

```
            - (void) configureMoviePlayer {


                if(self.moviePlayerController == nil) {

                    self.moviePlayerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

                    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
                    [self.moviePlayerController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

                    [self.view addSubview: [self.moviePlayerController view]];

                    NSDictionary *views = @{ @"selfview" : self.view, @"movieControllerView" : [self moviePlayerController].view};

                    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[movieControllerView]|"
                                                                                      options:0
                                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                                        views:views]];
                    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[movieControllerView]|"
                                                                                      options:0
                                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                                        views:views]];
                }

            }
```

When the stream URL is received, it is passed to a new player instance:

```
 self.moviePlayerController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:self.contentUrl];
 //self.moviePlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
 if([self.moviePlayerController respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsPictureInPicturePlayback)]) {                             

    self.moviePlayerController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = YES;
}
```

The example [in the WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-211/) does not contain the button. Is there a way to disable just the single button, or get the array of the default toolbar buttons and disable a specific one.

Comment: what about rolling your own AVPlayer implementtion? It's pretty simple and you can add custom controls as you wish

Comment: @Larcerax I have updated the question.Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform some action on Play and Pause actions of AVPlayer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038368/how-to-perform-some-action-on-play-and-pause-actions-of-avplayer)

Comment: @rkyr I am using the AVPlayerViewController not just the AVPlayer within a custom controller.

Comment: @VladimírSlavík linked question also about AVPlayerVeiwController

Comment: Also if subtitles view controller is presented, there is no "Done" or "Cancel" button to disable it. If one tap at the top right, the subtitles view controller is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, information here removed the unwanted button
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1801/_index.html

You need to explicitly declare that the content does not contain closed captions (with CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE, full details in the note above)