# How to perform some action on Play and Pause actions of AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have used `AVPlayer` to play video on my swift application. I want to place a Play button (custom button) at the middle of video. I know how to play and pause video on tapping the button.

I couldn't find how to show/hide the custom button when the video is played/paused from default buttons? Are there any listener or something which triggers when the video is played/paused?

I also want to hide the "Audio & Subtitles" icon from default control.

Comment: You can just set `playButton.enabled = false` and `playButton.alpha = 0` on the action. So when you click/tap the button, the other buttons (or that button as well) is disabled and it disappears. Make an `IBOutlet` out of that button however + an `IBAction`. @Narendra

Comment: @Lukeslvi, Thanks for the reply. But I did not mean how to show/hide the button but what I cant get is how to trigger the IBAction when the default play/pause button is tapped? Because you can not drag the touch up inside action to the IBAction for default buttons. E.g. lets say I go to the video screen and click on "Play" button (default), the video starts playing and I want to hide the custom button. Then after some time, I click on "Pause" button (default), the video is paused and I want to show the custom button. Hope its easy to understand the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can listen to player state changes and hide/show buttons: (assume your player is named `player`, and button is `playButton`)

```
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: .New, context: nil) // somewhere after player init
...
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
  if keyPath == "rate" {
    playButton.enabled = player.rate == 1 
  } else {
    super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
  }
}
```

If rate of player is equal to 0 it means that video is not playing.

Comment: I am working with AVPlayerController and add "rate" Observer. When i go offline at this situation the player pause. But it does not check "rate" observer method.

Comment: @SankalapYadurajSingh, please create new question if you have one. Or try to google it.

Comment: this my new question please visit.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411636/avplayerviewcontroller-play-pause-issue-in-ios?noredirect=1#comment66148154_39411636

Answer (score 0):

player init then,

```
self.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: .new, context: nil)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if self.player?.rate == 0 {
        print("Pause")
    }else {
        print("Play")
    }
}
```